# Getting Cm to ft values and displaying in other element gives reference error

Tags: javascript, html

I have the conversion math correct(looked it up here), but getting the value from the element that displays the height in cm, then parse it to ft/inch and display it on(on click) the right hand span does not work, i get a reference error(converter not defined).

I cannot figure out why it is undefined, is it because of hoisting or can the parseInt function not have the parameters as they are?

Here is the function

```
var displayInches = document.getElementById("heightInches");


displayInches.addEventListener("click", function() {
toFeet(converter);
});

function toFeet(converter) {
var heightOutputCM = document.getElementById("yourHeight");
 var converter = parseInt(heightOutputCM.value);
 var realFeet = converter * 0.3937 / 12;
 var feet = Math.floor(realFeet);
 var inches = Math.round((realFeet - feet) * 12);
 return feet + "and" + inches;
 }
```

Here is the link:

https://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/ZyRogX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<h1>Alcohol blood level calculator</h1>

<fieldset>
      <legend>Your Indicators</legend><br>
      <label for="height" class="margin">Height:</label>
      <span class="leftlabel" id=""><span id="yourHeight"></span>Cm</span>
      <input type="range" id="UserInputHeight" name="height" min="0" max="200" step="1" style="width: 200px">
      <span id="heightInchesSpan"  class="rightlabel"><span id="heightInches"></span>Ft</span>
      <br>
      <label for="" class="margin">Gender:</label>
      <span class="leftlabel">Male</span>
      <input type="range" id="salary" name="salary" min="0" max="1" style="width: 200px">
      <span class="rightlabel">Female</span>
 </fieldset>
```

JS

```
// get and display height

var displayHeightInput = document.getElementById("UserInputHeight");

displayHeightInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
  sliderChange(this.value);
});

function sliderChange(val) {
  var heightOutput = document.getElementById("yourHeight");
  heightOutput.innerHTML = val;
  toFeet();
  return val;
}


function toFeet() {
  var heightOutputCM = document.getElementById("yourHeight");
  var converter = parseInt(heightOutputCM.innerHTML); 
  var realFeet = converter * 0.3937 / 12;
  var feet = Math.floor(realFeet);
  var inches = Math.round((realFeet - feet) * 12); 
  document.getElementById("heightInches").innerHTML=feet + "and" + inches;
  return feet + " and " + inches;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but does not work. 
Looks like this bit is problemtaic:
var converter = parseInt(heightOutputCM.value);

Comment: you want to display the converted value anywhere?

Comment: yes, in the right span element with the default "ft". On click. Or a permanent updatelike on the left span element would be even better.

Comment: Perfect, so it was the ParseInt arguments. Very nice, learned a lot, these are the little quirks worth learning:-)

Comment: Yes, now it will update the feet value on sliding. Don't need to click the feet span

Comment: That is amazing, I thought I would need 2 return statements in the sliderChange fn, but had no idea I could just call the toFeet within sliderChange. I always kept functions very simple, but this is amazing stuff, thanks again.